# Leaflet JS widget in Filament won't execute

Tags: javascript, leaflet, alpine.js, laravel-filament, filamentphp

For a non-profit I'm creating a Filament admin panel with a widget running a [Leaflet.js](https://leafletjs.com/)  map.

I've set this up according to the [Filemant docs](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/support/assets#asynchronous-alpinejs-components)

All goes well, the data gets passed to the JS. But leaflet doesn't create the map. It seems that the L.map() command can't find the DIV I'm referrencing.

i've tried hardcoding it as const map = L.map('map'), L.map(document.getElementById('map')); L.map(this.$refs.leafletMap), L.map(this.$refs.leafletMap.id), ... none does the tric

Any help is hugely appreciated :)

**AdminPanelProvider.php**

```
class AdminPanelProvider extends PanelProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        FilamentAsset::register([
            Css::make('leaflet-1-9-4-css', 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css'),
            Js::make('leaflet-1-9-4-js', 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js'),
            AlpineComponent::make('visitor-heatmap-js', __DIR__ . '/../../../resources/js/leaflet-heatmap.js'),         
        ]);
    }
    
   ..
}
```

**visitor-heatmap-widget.blade**

```
<x-filament-widgets::widget>
    <x-filament::section>
    HEATMAP
        
        
        <div
            x-ignore
            ax-load
            ax-load-src="{{ \Filament\Support\Facades\FilamentAsset::getAlpineComponentSrc('visitor-heatmap-js') }}"
            x-data="leafletVisitorsHeatmap({
                cities: @js($data)
            })"
        >
            
                <div x-ref="leafletMap" id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">

                </div>
            
        </div>
    </x-filament::section>
</x-filament-widgets::widget>
```

**leaflet-heatmap.js (stripped to the bare minimum)**

```
export default function leafletVisitorsHeatmap({ cities }) 
{
    return {
 
        init: function () {
            console.log('start leafletVisitorsHeatmap');
            //console.log('cities:');
            //console.log(cities);
                    
            const map = L.map(this.$refs.leafletMap.id).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

            const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                maxZoom: 19,
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
            }).addTo(map);
            
            
        },
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error in the console? Try to wrap the map creation in a `setTimeout` with a 5 seconds to see if it is a timing problem.

Comment: no errors. if I remove the leaflet-package include it does show an error "L is not initialized" so it seems to me that Leaflet is correctly initialized but just can't find the map-object in the DOM. Timeout doesn't work :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! Turns out the div had a width but no height... So the map was drawn just not shown...

Resolved by updating my blade file to:

```
<div style="width=100vh;height:80vh;"       
            x-ignore
            ax-load
            ax-load-src="{{ \Filament\Support\Facades\FilamentAsset::getAlpineComponentSrc('visitor-heatmap-js') }}"
            x-data="leafletVisitorsHeatmap({
                cities: @js($data)
            })"
        >           
                <div x-ref="map" id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
                </div>
            
        </div>
```